# Consideration of increased difficulty to achieve reputation given elevated strictness

Tags: discussion, reputation

This question is prompted by a vote to close on a recent posting (not mine!) that seems well interesting and useful.

Rather than point out the precise question, we will probably mostly agree there is a heightened vigilance vs a few years back.  One can simply look at the questions from that timeframe that were closed or migrated months or even years later.

Here is an illustration from the earliest days:  over 2000 upvotes on a straightforward question.

[What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/6400990#6400990)

Now I have personally managed to get a basic minimal quorum of reputation that permits me to work well enough within SOF (a bit over 1400) so this question is more of curiosity.

Given the heightened scrutiny and restrictions, what is the rationale for not increasing the point scales in the present relative to (at least several years..) past - to reflect the higher bars to hurdle?

**UPDATE**  The anser provided focused too much on the specific example of question that I put here.  So, how about this one?  Over 1000 upvotes, by virtue of it being basically near the inception of SO.  This is what I mean by "older questions have relatively higher associated reputation independent of their quality".

[Difference between URI and URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176264/whats-the-difference-between-a-uri-and-a-url)

My contention is *not* that the question were poor or not useful. Rather that it is obvious and straightforward. I think all of us reading this question have put many ones out there requiring well more thought and planning and have received, well, less than 1000 upvotes ;).

Let us at least agree that older questions had a better chance of attaining high votes/reputation scores.

Comment: Bear in mind that not all those upvotes resulted in reputation gain because of the daily limit.

Comment: Sure but 200 points per day times a number of different days is still pretty juicy. In addition, the daily limit rule may not have even been in effect at the time of that OP.  The more general idea is that: rules, guidelines, and enforcement have changed dramatically over time.

Comment: Yeah, but still. That question was very likely reddited, it has a half million views. It is not typical. I agree it's a bit unfair but these mega-upvoted questions are relatively rare overall - and they can still happen, just on different kinds of questions.  It's more a question of luck than old age.

Comment: New questions are well more vetted and quickly disposed of than in the past. We can look at the questions that were open for months or years and then policies changed and they were closed. The  closed but left on site "for historical reasons". Those questions would have never gained the votes in the present incarnation of SOF.

Comment: True, but the question isn't mega-upvoted because it's old. It's mega-upvoted because it caught a lot of attention. [That can still happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) Yes, most of those mega-upvoted questions are admittedly old, but you will still see it happening. And either way, those lucky few questions still don't make much of a difference in the long run. So some users have ill-gotten rep through mega-upvotes - so what? Others have rep from thousands of mediocre questions, or answers. What's the difference?

Comment: I am not suggesting that it were completely impossible for new questions to become popular and receive votes. However the bar is much higher and many of the earlier questions would not have lived long under the current restrictions. Therefore the effective difficulty/value of reputation is higher in the present. There is however no calibration in the current system.

Comment: Another consideration: going to the past even simple questions had not yet been asked. Fundamental questions about language usage are going to get many views: but once the question has been asked it should not be repeated. Questions tend to be more focused over time as the general ones have already been addressed. This leads to lower views per question although in many cases they may have required more homework.

Comment: I guess the general consensus is there isn't need for a calibration because rep is an extremely flaky measure anyway. The changes you describe are of course real, but do they matter? As said, there are so many "wrong" ways of getting rep anyway... There's previous discussion on this but I can't find it right now. (BTW slightly related, just if you're interested, [here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136059) a breakdown on what user groups would be affected if the reputation gained on those highly upvoted qustions would be limited... it's not the high-rep users, surprisingly (to me))

Comment: Your comments have been helpful. There will not likely be a complete answer svailable because of the volume of preceding discussion about reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason older questions get more upvotes and rep is multi-factored:

1. The rules were different back then.
2. A lot of people have the same questions and find them useful.
3. They have had a lot of extra time to gain said upvotes.

Not all old questions are highly scored, and not all highly scored questions are old. It's also worth noting that, since rules were more lax, some of the highly upvoted questions of the past are also *closed* or *historically locked* to show that they are no longer acceptable questions here.

The two that you link in the question aren't just highly upvoted, but extremely highly upvoted. This is because not only are they old, but they are *basic questions* that gain a lot from point two of my list above with a lot of time to gain votes, as mentioned in point three. A lot of basic questions that would get a lot of views, and votes, nowadays are already asked. They're far more likely to be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

This is why I'm a big believer in *Canonical/Reference questions,* which is essentially what the cited question is.

Canonical Questions

1. Are useful to more than just one person
2. Can be used as a target to close trivial questions where the person didn't even bother to Google for the answer
3. Are rewarded with reputation

What's not to like?  Of course, the trick is to **ask a good question.** The even trickier part is to **write a good answer.**  Your cited question accomplishes both, which is why it earned so much reputation (the fact that it has a half million views certainly didn't hurt).

Comment: No arguments about canonical questions. But that still leaves unaddressed other aspects that I raised, and which are not based upon quality of questions/answers.  In any case the whole area of reputation has apparently been overly hashed out /  discussed  already - per the link provided by @Pekka.  So attempting to discuss further tweaks is probably not the best use of moderators' energies

Comment: I have updated the OP for another example (highly upvoted) question.  Your answer on canonical questions only addresses a fraction of the cases I have addressed.